# Does UPS Address Validation API works in mobile app?

Tags: validation, street-address, ups

I am learning UPS address validation API for my PHP application. Going to use web service version for my integration. However I am not sure whether UPS address validation will work for mobile app or not like iPhone or Android app. Can someone answer me this question in details?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you have a library to parse XML. Are you shipping via UPS from mobile devices?

Comment: no I am learning the UPS API..have a plan to develop a mobile app and use UPS Address Validation API there

Comment: Okay. Well, just keep in mind that unless you're shipping via UPS, they don't allow use of their API. For general-purpose address validation, you'll want to a more general, specialized CASS-Certified vendor. For example, I work at SmartyStreets (smartystreets.com) where we have an API called LiveAddress (www.smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api). Make sure you find a service where the TOS meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Matt's comment, UPS address verification and official postal (e.g. USPS, Canada Post) addresses can be different so, in addition to the terms of service, make sure you are pulling from the right data.

Comment: thx Matt. Can you provide me little bit details of the API which I can use for general purpose address validation? Any link.